# StringTemplate getInstanceOf returns null

Tags: java, antlr, stringtemplate-4

Good Day!

I started using StringTemplate and I encountered a pretty annoying problem. I have a simple Template "T.st"

```
T(name, email, passwort) ::= << ... >>
```

It is saved in a directory "templates" which is part of my source folder "src/main/resources". When i execute following lines

```
STGroup group = new STGroupDir("templates");
ST st = group.getInstanceOf("T");
```

the root field of the group variable has the value "jar:file:/D:/path/to/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/wtpwebapps/application/WEB-INF/lib/service.jar!/templates/"

But st will be null, even though the groupdir was apparently found, because it exists within the given service.jar and when I change the dir name to something non-existent I get an exception that the directory doesn't exist. But i'm not sure why I can't get an instance of my T template.

Let's say i save my templates in "C:/templates" and use this to get the STGroup I will eventually get a valid instance and can render a correct string. Why is there a difference if my template is stored in a normal directory (working) or a directory within my service.jar (not working)?

regards